# How to select a random node when nodes are untrusted in a distributed network?

Tags: distributed-systems, randomness, random-walks

Assume in a distributed network, where the nodes are not trusted and are identified by their public keys, we intend to select one of them in a random process. In such a situation, all of the nodes have the same chances to be elected.

Since the system is not centralized and there is no trusted server performing the election process, how to select one of the nodes truly randomly (where each of the nodes is able to manipulate the client code such that they would be elected in all the rounds)?

**Complementary explanation:** I mean that as there is no trusted and centralized server to perform the randomness process, thus it is performed locally in each node by a client code, such that each node can be able to manipulate the client code to be always elected. Assume there are 10 nodes, each of which has a client code to perform a decentralized randomness process. What happens if one of them manipulate the code to be elected in all the rounds? And how to prevent such malicious behavior?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_multi-party_computation, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_flipping#Telecommunications, https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/767/351, https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15136/351, https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3705/351, https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/86870/351, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leader_election

Comment: Cross-posted: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/238437/971, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/152140/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.